# Direct limit and products

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Any of your comments (or if you know a resource which could be handy) regarding this problem would be appreciated:

**Show that finite products commute with filtered direct limits.**

Got no idea how to use those finite and filtered properties!

Comment: are you working on a particular category?

Comment: Category of sets indeed.

Comment: Steve Lack wrote a proof in this MathOverflow [question of his](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57099/why-do-filtered-colimits-commute-with-finite-limits).

Comment: The StackExchange software noticed my answer was trivial and converted it to a comment. Cool. I'm surprised it hasn't noticed how trivial some of my other answers are.

Comment: The property doesn't hold in any category, though.

Comment: Usually, "... doesn't hold in any ..." means "never holds", @MartinBrandenburg, you probably meant to say "doesn't hold in every category", since it does hold in some, such as the category of sets which is the one Sean said he was interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the proof of this fact in

> Borceux F. Handbook of categorical algebra. Vol.1, Theorem 2.13.4.